# rake db:create rake aborted did you mean? db:create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, docker-compose, ruby-on-rails-5

I am new to rails and I have created a stack that is working on my machine but when I uninstalled it and reinstalled it for testing it gave me this error related to the init.sh file which I run to create & migrate & seed my database at the initialization.

rails version: 5.2.8.1

rake aborted!
' (See the list of available tasks with rake --tasks) 
Did you mean?  db:create 
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in <top (required)> 
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in load' 
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in ' 
(See full trace by running task with --trace) 
rake aborted! 
' (See the list of available tasks with rake --tasks)

init.sh

```bash
rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid
rake db:create && rake db:migrate
rake db:seed
rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
rake es:create_index
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:  
  db:  
    image: mysql:5.7
    restart: always
    environment:  
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: app
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
  redis:  
    image: redis:7.0.5
    restart: always
    command: redis-server
    ports:
      - "6379:6379"
    volumes:
      - "redis:/data"
  sidekiq:
    depends_on:
      - 'db'
      - 'redis'
    build: .
    command: bundle exec sidekiq
    volumes:
      - '.:/chatsystem'
    environment:
      REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ : 'redis://redis:6379/1'
  elasticsearch:
    image: elasticsearch:7.17.1
    restart: always
    environment:
      - cluster.name=cluster_name
      - bootstrap.memory_lock=true
      - network.host=0.0.0.0
      - http.port = 9200
      - transport.host=0.0.0.0
      - discovery.type=single-node
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
    ulimits:
      memlock:
        soft: -1
        hard: -1
  app:
    build: .
    command: sh -c 'sh ./init.sh && rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0''
    restart: always
    volumes:
        - ".:/chatsystem"
    ports:  
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:  
      - db
      - redis
    links:
      - db
      - redis
    environment :
      DB_USER: root
      DB_NAME: noteapp
      DB_PASSWORD: password
      DB_HOST: db
      REDIS_URL_SIDEKIQ : 'redis://redis:6379/1'
      ELASTIC_HOST: elasticsearch
      ELASTIC_PORT: 9200
      
volumes:
  redis:
```

Comment: You should be using `rails db:create`. The rake tasks where moved into the Rails executable many many  years ago. Make sure you're using up-to-date guides/sources.

Comment: then how was it working on my machine? also I am using rails 5

Comment: i did what you said but still the same it just changed to rails aborted @max

Comment: Why are you using an ancient version of Rails? Support for Rails 5.2 was dropped 5 months ago.

Comment: Are you sure you're posting the full backtrace? The suggestion `Did you mean ...?` is usually displayed when Rake doesn't recognize the task you invoke, but in this case the first thing it says is smth. like `Don't know how to build task <...>`...

Comment: Are you by any chance on a Windows host?  I'm wondering if the slightly odd output is because the script has DOS line endings, and so Rake is trying to run tasks like `db:migrate\r`.

Answer (score 0):

Run db:setup if you want  db:create && db:migrate && db:seed

Comment: same error:
rake aborted!
' (See the list of available tasks with `rake --tasks`)
Did you mean?  db:setup
/usr/local/bundle/gems/rake-13.0.6/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
rake aborted